What does the run-time cost of laying down a function activation record depend on?
I was reading Bjarne Stroustrup's "Principle and Practice using C++" when I encountered the following in chapter 8.5.8 about call stacks and activation records:

For reasonable functions (such as every function we directly or indirectly use in this book), the run-time cost of laying down a function activation record doesn’t depend on how big it is.

But, he did not explain what the run-time cost did actually depend on.

The answer will be very dependent on the platform, but generally speaking the cost of an activation record is fixed to putting a return address and frame pointer on the stack and allocating space for local variables.
Very occasionally these actions will hit the "stack guard page" which triggers the OS to allocate some more memory pages for the stack, but this cost is proportional to call stack depth and thus amortized over all of your function calls.

I admit I understand very little about OSes, but isn't the stack typically statically sized and preallocated? Which is the entire reason why stack overflows are not recoverable?

The minimum and maximum sizes are set, yes. But modern OSes do not allocate actual memory pages for the full (typical) 8MB. They allocate a handful of pages and set up memory attributes such that acceses beyond that trigger a page fault. The handler for this allocates more pages for the stack. (up to the maximum) See this question for example, or The Old New Thing blog on this.

A clarification: "allocating space for local variables" typically means making a single adjustment to the stack pointer. It's not like calling an allocation function to get memory from a pool.

The answer generally depends on that platform.
However, virtually every modern architecture has some notion of a stack, delimited by a "stack pointer".
Activation records contain (among other things) function parameters, the return address, etc. and obtaining more space is as simple as modifying the stack pointer.
Consider the (unoptimized) assembly generated by GCC for this simple program:
struct big {
    char bytes[32];
};

void foo(big);

int main() {
    foo({}); // temporary object
}

main:
  push rbp
  mov rbp, rsp
  sub rsp, 32
  pxor xmm0, xmm0
  movaps XMMWORD PTR [rbp-32], xmm0
  movaps XMMWORD PTR [rbp-16], xmm0
  sub rsp, 32
  // ...
  call foo(big)

The two sub rsp, 32 instruction obtain space for the local big inside main and the function parameter object in foo, respectively.
It doesn't matter how big big is, the run-time cost of "laying down the activation record" is this single instruction.
The remaining work is initializing or copying the big object, but that is separate cost, and can obviously vary from function to function.
Perhaps Bjarne would consider an "unreasonable function" to be one that uses local objects so massive that you either overflow the stack immediately, or need to make system calls to resize the stack (the default maximum size is typically 1 - 8 MiB but can be adjusted).
To answer the question of what the cost does depend on ... well, it's typically constant.
Hitting a "stack guard page" or accessing a page of the stack that's been evicted from CPU cache may lead to increased run-time cost at times.
However, it's not really possible for the developer to account for these fluctuations and it's not something they usually have to worry about.
